# Varioref's "Preceding Page" broken when cleveref is loaded

Tags: cleveref, varioref

I'm using varioref together with `hyperref` and `cleveref`. Everything works fine except that as soon as I load `cleveref`, `varioref` forgets about "on the preceding page" and simply uses "on page N".

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{cleveref} %Uncomment to break "preceding page"

\begin{document}

\chapter{Preceding}
\label{Preceding}
\clearpage

\vref{Preceding} -- %should give: "1 on the preceding page", broken with cleveref
\vref{Facing} %works correctly with and without cleveref

\clearpage
\chapter{Facing}
\label{Facing}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

BTW: I use `hyperref` here because its strong interaction with both other packages. The bug still occurs without it.

Comment: From the `cleverref` manual: *Similarly, if
varioref is loaded, cleveref redefines the \vref, \vrefrange, \fullref*

Comment: Interchanging the loading order of `\varioref` and `cleveref` will give the expected text with `preceding`, but I am not sure about other consequences of this.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately interchanging `varioref` and `cleverref` breaks the use of `\cref{Preceding}` for me. I'm afraid someone has to help me dig into the redefinition done by `cleveref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed in the latest pre-release version `cleveref` version 0.19.1 (released May 2014), which is not yet available on CTAN. It can be downloaded from the author's website at http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.php#cleveref-docs.

**Download:**
Direct download link: http://www.dr-qubit.org/download.php?file=latex/cleveref-0.19.1.tar.gz

**Installation:** From the author's website:

> To install the package, follow the usual DocTeX installation procedure: extract the files, run the `cleveref.ins` file through LaTeX, copy the resulting `cleveref.sty` file to a directory in your TeX path, and run `texhash` (or equivalent) to update your TeX database.